# Uncaught TypeError: table.rows[i].cells[j].querySelector(...) is null?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
$(document).on("change", "select", function () {
  $(".vcheck").html();
  console.log(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text);
});

$(document).on("keypress", "input", function () {
  $(".vcheck").html();
  console.log(this.value);
});

$(document).on("click", "#devSaveBtn", function () {
  var answer = window.confirm("Save changes");
  if (answer) {
    // * Table variable
    var table = document.getElementById("steptable");

    // * Input variable
    var getInput = document.querySelectorAll(".vcheck");

    // * Loop to get the input & dropdown values
    for (var i = 0; i < getInput.length; i++)
      console.log(getInput[i].id, " => Input", i, " = ", getInput[i].value);

    for (var i = 0, row; (row = table.rows[i]); i++) {
      // * iterate through rows
      // * rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop

      for (var j = 0, col; (col = row.cells[j]); j++) {
        // * iterate through columns
        // * columns would be accessed using the "col" variable assigned in the for loop

        var ObjType = table.rows[i].cells[2].querySelector(".vcheck").value;
        var Name = table.rows[i].cells[3].querySelector(".vcheck").value;
        var Business = table.rows[i].cells[4].querySelector(".vcheck").value;
        var Project = table.rows[i].cells[5].querySelector(".vcheck").value;
        var Deployer_Candidate =
          table.rows[i].cells[6].querySelector(".vcheck").value;
        var Description = table.rows[i].cells[7].querySelector(".vcheck").value;
        console.log("ObjType = " + ObjType);
        console.log(col);
      }
    }
  }
  // * else display service message
  else {
    console.log("Service Cancel");
  }
});
```

```html
     <!-- * Main Record Table *-->
                    <div id="steptablecontainer">
                        <div id="steptable_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper no-footer">
                            <table id="steptable" class="compact cell-border no-footer dataTable row-border"
                                role="grid">
                                <thead id="recordTableHead">
                                    <tr role="row">
                                        <!-- * Names For Each Container *-->
                                        <th class="noncomponentswidth sorting_disabled" tabindex="0"
                                            aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label=""
                                            style="width: 25px; max-width: 25px;"></th>
                                        <th class="noncomponentswidth sorting_disabled" tabindex="0"
                                            aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label=""
                                            style="width: 50px; background-image: none; max-width: 25px;">Record</th>
                                        <th class="componentellipsis sorting_disabled" tabindex="0"
                                            aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Component"
                                            style="width: 200px; max-width: 50px;">Type</th>
                                        <th class="noncomponentswidth sorting_disabled" tabindex="0"
                                            aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Type"
                                            style="width: 125px;">Name</th>
                                        <th class="noncomponentswidth sorting_disabled" tabindex="0"
                                            aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Test"
                                            style="width: 100px; max-width: 50px;">Business</th>
                                        <th class="noncomponentswidth sorting_disabled" tabindex="0"
                                            aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Dev"
                                            style="width: 200px; max-width: 50px;">Project</th>
                                        <th class="noncomponentswidth sorting_disabled" tabindex="0"
                                            aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Type"
                                            style="width: 150px; max-width: 125px;">Deployer Candidate</th>
                                        <th class="noncomponentswidth sorting_disabled" tabindex="0"
                                            aria-controls="steptable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Type"
                                            style="width: 400px; max-width: 200px; overflow: hidden;">Description
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <!-- * Sample Record (Cloned then changed) *-->

                                <tbody id="recordRow0" style="display: none; border: 10px;" class="recordRow">
                                    <tr role="row" class="" data-true-step="1">
                                        <td class="noncomponentswidth">
                                            <button class="readyonlyhidden" id="removeRecordBtn0" title="Remove Record"
                                                value="0">
                                                <span><i style="font-size:18px;" class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></span>
                                            </button>
                                        </td>


                                        <!-- * Record intializing *-->
                                        <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="recordCount">1</td>

                                        <!-- * Drop down for the obj_type *-->
                                        <div id="container">
                                            <td class="componentellipsis" id="recordTypeWrapper">
                                                <select id="OBJ_TYPE" class="vcheck">
                                                    <option value="TP">TP</option>
                                                    <option value="Workflow">Workflow</option>
                                                    <option value="Package">Package</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </td>
                                        </div>


                                        <!-- * Container for Obj Name *-->
                                        <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="recordObjName">
                                            <p>
                                                <!-- * Input for Obj Name *-->
                                                <input type="text" id="OBJ_NAME" name="Object Name" placeholder=""
                                                    class="vcheck" required minlength="8">
                                            </p>
                                        </td>

                                        <!-- * Deployer Business *-->
                                        <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="recordDevName">
                                            <input type="text" id="DEPLOYER_BUSINESS" name="Business Name"
                                                placeholder="" style="display: none;">
                                            <select id="DEPLOYER_BUSINESS" class="vcheck">
                                                <!-- * Picklist for TP *-->
                                                <option value="APPM">APPM</option>
                                                <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
                                                <option value="CorporateAP">CorporateAP</option>
                                                <option value="CorporateCredit">CorporateCredit</option>
                                                <option value="CorporateEHS">CorporateEHS</option>
                                                <option value="CorporateFinance">CorporateFinance</option>
                                                <option value="CorporateFinancialServices">
                                                    CorporateFinancialServices
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="CorporateHR">CorporateHR</option>
                                                <option value="CorporateIT">CorporateIT</option>
                                                <option value="CorporateLegal">CorporateLegal</option>
                                                <option value="CorporateLogistics">CorporateLogistics</option>
                                                <option value="CorporateTax">CorporateTax</option>
                                                <option value="EMEAPackaging">EMEAPackaging</option>
                                                <option value="EMEAPapers">EMEAPapers</option>
                                                <option value="GCF">GCF</option>
                                                <option value="MillManufacturing">MillManufacturing</option>
                                                <option value="MillSupport">MillSupport</option>
                                                <option value="NAIPGContainer">NAIPGContainer</option>
                                                <option value="NAIPGContainerboard">NAIPGContainerboard</option>
                                                <option value="NAIPGRecycling">NAIPGRecycling</option>
                                                <option value="NAP">NAP</option>
                                                <option value="SouthAmerica">SouthAmerica</option>
                                                <option value="zConnectivity">zConnectivity</option>
                                                <option value="zSylvamo">zSylvamo</option>
                                            </select>

                                        </td>

                                        <!-- * Input for Deployer Project *-->
                                        <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="recordProjectName">
                                            <input type="text" id="DEPLOYER_PROJECT" name="Project Name" class="vcheck"
                                                placeholder="">
                                        </td>


                                        <!-- * Deployer_Candidate *-->
                                        <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="titleDeployerCandidate">
                                            <select id="DEPLOYER_CANDIDATE" class="vcheck">

                                                <!-- * Picklist for TP *-->
                                                <option value="PRODJ (wm53a/b/c 10000)">PRODJ (wm53a/b/c 10000)
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="PRODR (wm53a/b/c 12000)">PRODR (wm53a/b/c 12000)
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="PRODXA (wm54a/b/c 21000)">PRODXA (wm54a/b/c
                                                    21000)
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="PRODXS (wm54a/b/c 20000)">PRODXS (wm54a/b/c
                                                    20000)
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="PRODXE (wm53a/b/c 11000)">PRODXE (wm53a/b/c
                                                    11000)
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="-------------------">-------------------</option>
                                                <option value="PRODAD1 (wm54a/b/c 60000)">PRODAD1 (wm54a/b/c 60000)
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="PRODAD2 (wm54a/b/c 61000)">PRODAD2 (wm54a/b/c 61000)
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="-------------------">-------------------</option>
                                                <option value="MAPGRP1 (wm52a/b/c 40k/41k/42k)">MAPGRP1
                                                    (wm52a/b/c
                                                    40k/41k/42k)</option>
                                            </select>

                                        </td>

                                        <!-- * Input for Description *-->
                                        <td class="noncomponentswidth" id="recordDeployerCandidate" placeholder="">
                                            <input type="text" id="DESCRIPTION" name="Description" placeholder=""
                                                class="vcheck" style="resize: vertical; width: 100%; height: 4.5em;"
                                                </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>

                            <!-- * Add & Remove buttons *-->
                            <div class="btn-group2">
                                <div id="addRemoveButons" class="dt-buttons" style="visibility:hidden">
                                    <button class="readonlyhidden" tabindex="0" aria-controls="steptable" type="button"
                                        id="recordAddBtn2" title="Add new record" style="display: inline-block;">
                                        <span><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></span>
                                    </button>
                                    <button class="readonlyhidden" tabindex="0" aria-controls="steptable" type="button"
                                        id="recordAddBtn" title="Add new record">
                                        <span><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></span>
                                    </button>
                                    <button class="readonlyhidden" tabindex="0" aria-controls="steptable" type="button"
                                        id="recordRemoveBtn" title="Remove last record" style="display: none">
                                        <span><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></span>
                                    </button>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I am trying to get all the values from my table columns and log them but whenever I do that I am getting that it is null. But if I use an on change function or key press function it records it in the console as I type it or select it. Note every new record is a clone of the original recordRow0. The original is clone and than hidden

Comment: row 0 doesn't contain `.vcheck` items, it contains `<th>` elements.  Since you are doing some calculations on each row, you don't need to loop through each column.

Comment: But I have a table that can have multiple rows. Wouldn't I need to loop through each column to get the values? This is what my table looks like https://imgur.com/a/ie485PS

Comment: You're referencing the individual columns by explicit indices, like `table.rows[i].cells[5]` - you never use `j` to reference a column (or use the `col` variable).  So you only need to loop through the rows if you're doing that.

Comment: So I just need to delete the second loop?

Comment: Start the row loop from 1, since row 0 is the th elements.

Comment: ...............OMG THAT WORK! https://imgur.com/a/2FfpH4O

Comment: Hopefully I can just use this variables in my sql query and update my database accordingly with the data from this now